# ion-label does not disappear when in browser with mobile toogle device toolbar

Tags: ionic-framework

the code is like this:

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-item>
   <ion-label>account</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>

 <ion-item>
   <ion-label>password</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>

 <ion-item  *ngIf="needIp">
    <ion-label>your server ip:</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="serverIp"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

and which is show in browser [like](https://leanote.com/api/file/getImage?fileId=5b5abe1eab64416fb90013a4) this.

and when i set the browser toogle device toolbar with android mode, the content in ion-label did not disappear, [like](https://leanote.com/api/file/getImage?fileId=5b5abeb3ab644171a60012f7) this.

i don't why, when i build this project with a app,the ionic app can show normally . but when i run the project with "ionic serve" command, and run it in chrome, there will is a bug in ion-label.

Comment: What is your width, height and zoom when viewing the app on chrome device mode?

Comment: 375 * 667, i found that the problem will occur on ios, i tried to solve it by the link:https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/6272,  but it did not work.